# Adding a style sheet in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, psd

I am new to Wordpress and I need to convert a PSD int a Wordpress theme. 
For that I downloaded a naked wordpress theme to start with and I tried to add my own css style in function.php as follows:

```
function naked_scripts()  { 

// get the theme directory style.css and link to it in the header
wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style/main.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'responsive-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style/responsive.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style/bootstrap.min.css' );


// add fitvid
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.10.2', true );

// add theme scripts
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '3.0.3', true );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'naked_scripts' ); // Register this fxn and   allow Wordpress to call it automatcally in the header
```

but in the browser I did not get my style and I have his error:

```
 GET http://rota.alwaysdata.net/wp-content/themes/theme1/style/main.css?ver=4.1
```

what's ver=4.1 ??

Comment: http://underscores.me/ is a best place to setup a wordrpess tempalte than make changes as required by your PSD template.

Answer (score 1):

It's a cache-buster added by WordPress. You can set it to any number you want using the `$ver` argument in `wp_enqueue_style`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

The ?ver=X.XX has **NO** effect on the content of the stylesheet.

CSS Cache-busting references:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/prevent-css-caching/
https://www.mojowill.com/developer/get-your-wordpress-css-changes-noticed-immediately/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest if it's your first time creating a wordpress template using these resources:

1. Underscores blank wordpress theme:
   http://underscores.me/
2. Lynda.com underscores tutorial:
   http://www.lynda.com/underscores-tutorials/WordPress-Building-Themes-from-Scratch-Using-Underscores/163092-2.html

This is what i used to make my first wordpress project and it worked out grate , here is the result: ibreatheart.com

Hope it helps .